# Choppy online playback and browsing

Tags: video, flash, 17.04, radeon, chromium

I wanna say that I'm new to Linux systems so there might be obvious things that I missed. I had Linux mint 17 on my Dell Latitude D531, was working fine with some problems regarding booting until something crashed completely and I had to format the HDD. Now I have Ubuntu 17.04 installed and everything is smooth and nice except for video content online (youtube works just fine though)
In Chromium the problem is even there when normally browsing sometimes; scrolling is often choppy, and watching a video is a nightmare (apart from youtube!). 
In firefox the problem is there but only with videos and a bit different(by chromium it looks like slow flickering frames of the video).

p.s. videos saved locally run completely normal! even those in HD.
I already tried everything I could find related to the issue; flash player, drivers, updates, cache limit etc..

```
Specs:
------
-CPU
          description: CPU
          product: AMD Turion(tm) 64 X2 Mobile Technology TL-56
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 400
          bus info: cpu@0
          slot: Microprocessor
          size: 800MHz
          capacity: 1800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz

-Memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 1000
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB

-Display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: RS690M [Radeon Xpress 1200/1250/1270]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 5
                bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=radeon latency=64
                resources: irq:26 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fe9f0000-fe9fffff ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fea00000-feafffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: The CPU and GPU listed above are about 10 years old. It's probably best to switch to a lighter distro like Xubuntu, disable smooth scrolling in FF, and not expect too much of that machine. It's not going to get any newer.

Comment: I realize that this laptop is very old and am using it temporarily, however, I didn't have this problem with linux mint! and how does youtube run so smoothly while other websites struggle at the same resolution!! 

If you think the only solution to this is switching to a lighter system, what would you prefer out of these:
-Xubuntu (after your suggestion)
-Linux mint (since it was running fine on the same machine)
-Windows XP
-Windows 7

Comment: Use what works best for you, and if not sure, test to find out. I'd not listen to anyone's advice on this. Different streaming sites utilize different codecs, it's only natural that some of them won't work well on very old hardware. Why that is or who is to blame or what's the solution are all moot points. You can open a discussion thread on any of the linux related forums, and ask for people's opinions.

Comment: I'd prefer win7 coz I'll be giving this laptop to my little sister in a few months and it's a lot easier for a normal user. But I'm afraid win7 would be too much for the hardware. 
I guess I'll have to try each one!

Comment: I have the same issue with an old computer (Windows sucks more, so don't even go there). Video: `Radeon Xpress 1200/1250/1270` with choppy windows when dragging. Poor performance in general for such a lightweight system. it is a Fujitsu Siemens Amilo Pa 2510.